# Background thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new in java I am searching for a **background thread in java** which runs periodically even after the **java desktop app is closed**.
I need a thing similar to **Service** in **Android** .
I searched for it but I found just threads no service.
I have to send data to the server which will be store in **config.propertise** file through that **background Thread** or **Service**.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app - Does this help?

Comment: Thanks but This is not that service

Comment: Uhh, you're wrong, that's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a unusual way to do it. it work for me always.
You have to do a certain task after the user close the app, Right???
.
Just override the close button functionality and hide the window on close action.
And continue your work in thread.
When your work is finished close your app using

```
 System.exit
```

User will never know that the app is running in background.

Comment: There are better answers than this. Why is this the accepted answer or  be worth a bounty?

Comment: May be because he is doing this :)

Answer (score 5):

A thread is contained within a process, so it doesn't make sense to talk about threads that run after the app is closed.

You either want:

- A separate service, like @BatScream suggested, which is a process that runs in the background without an app window connected to it.
- A scheduled task that uses Windows scheduled tasks mechanism to run some process periodically. See [Running a JAVA program as a scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12034177/7581)
- Or you want your app to minimize to the tray. See [How do I put a Java app in the system tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758083/7581)

Comment: okay supppose I had made the Windows service following http://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/build-windows-service-from-java-application-with-procrun/ Now where can I write the code which sends data to the server periodically even after the app is closed

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing by using a timer class.
O.w background services are here 
[How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Answer (score 0):

Base one [this](http://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/build-windows-service-from-java-application-with-procrun/), create a Java program, which will be used as a service with Linux crontab or Windows scheduler.

```
public class SomeService
{
    // Your task will repeat itself periodically (here every minute), until it is stopped
    private static final int SLEEP_TIME = 60000;

    private static boolean stop = false;

    public static void start(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("start");
        while (!stop)
        {
            sendDataToServer();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    private void sendDataToServer()
    {
        // TODO your job here
    }

    public static void stop(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("stop");
        stop = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if ("start".equals(args[0]))
        {
            start(args);
        }
        else if ("stop".equals(args[0]))
        {
            stop(args);
        }
    }
}
```